# Can we make copy of a static file in Django?

Tags: python, django, excel, file, file-copying

My requirement is to write into a sample excel (static) file, and download the copied static file in the device. The copy is required cause the sample file contains some formatting, which I need in the downloaded file as well.

> ```
> Directory Structure : 
>   
> Django Project     
>     - project     
>     - app     
>     - static         
>         - files             
>             -> sample.xlsx         
>         - css         
>         - js       
>     - manage.py
> ```

Now, I need to create a copy of `sample.xlsx` file, write some details in it and download it.

I've tried below code, in which I am creating a new file and copying the content from `sample.xlsx` to `new_file.xlsx` . But it does not copy the formatting from `sample.xlsx`

```
def exportXLS(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="new_file.xlsx"'

    sample = load_workbook(sample_file_path)  #opening sample.xlsx
    active_sheet = sample.worksheets[0] 
    
    new_workbook = Workbook() #creating new excel file
    worksheet = wb.active
    worksheet.title = "Sheet Name"
    
    mr = active_sheet.max_row 
    mc = active_sheet.max_column 
    
    #copying values from sample.xlsx to new_file.xlsx
    for i in range (1, mr + 1): 
        for j in range (1, mc + 1): 
            c = active_sheet.cell(row = i, column = j) 
            worksheet.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c.value
    
    new_workbook.save(response)

    return response
```

==> I would like to make a COPY of `sample.xlsx` first then write the details in the copy, then download it.

Comment: What are `load_workbook()` and `Workbook()`?